# Run time error 1101 while populating a project file

Tags: vba, excel

I am pretty new to VBA. I am trying to develop a macro to read an Excel file and populate data in a Project file. The Excel file has around 800 rows. I am debugging the code. While populating the Project file, in For loop, after executing the loop for many times, I am getting "run-time error '1101': The argument value is not valid."
Could you please help me with your inputs to understand the problem? Please find below the code.
Regards
Keya

```
Sub upload_excel_to_mpp()

'Declaration
Dim wbBook As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
Dim vaWorkorder As Variant
Dim vaTaskname As Variant
Dim vaHours As Variant
Dim vaArea As Variant
Dim vaSkill As Variant
Dim vaStatus As Variant
Dim lnStart As Long
Dim lnLastrow As Long
Dim lnCounter As Long

Set wbBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1)


'Populate the variables with values from Worksheet
 With wsSheet
    lnStart = .Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row
    vaWorkorder = .Range("A2:A" & lnStart).Value
    vaTaskname = .Range("E2:E" & lnStart).Value
    vaHours = .Range("F2:F" & lnStart).Value
    vaArea = .Range("G2:G" & lnStart).Value
    vaSkill = .Range("H2:H" & lnStart).Value
End With

'Instantiate and open MS Project and the project
'Need to add MS project libraries by going to tools->references
Dim prApp As MSProject.Application
Dim prProject As MSProject.Project
    Set prApp = New MSProject.Application
    prApp.FileOpen "C:\Users\manub\Desktop\work\Quantas\Qantaslink template.mpp"
    Set prProject = prApp.ActiveProject
     'Add task and other wanted information to the project.
    With prProject
      For lnCounter = 1 To UBound(vaTaskname)
            .Tasks.Add vaTaskname(lnCounter, 1)
            With .Tasks(vaTaskname(lnCounter, 1))
                .Text2 = vaWorkorder(lnCounter, 1)
                .Work = vaHours(lnCounter, 1)
                .Text8 = vaSkill(lnCounter, 1)
               .Text6 = vaArea(lnCounter, 1)
            End With
        Next lnCounter
    End With

     'Save the project and close MS Project.
    With prApp
        .FileSave
        .Quit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done!", vbInformation
     'Release objects from memory.
    Set prProject = Nothing
    Set prApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Your loop shouldn't run because `vaTaskName` isn't an array, and because it is not an array it also doesn't have a UBound.which is the limit of your loop. However, this doesn't explain the error message you quote. That would be explained by the highlight the Debugger will add to the line of code which causes the error. Which one is it?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting the error when lnCounter= 497 at line                                                                                                          .Work = vaHours(lnCounter, 1)

Comment: Add a line of code before that line: `If InCounter = 497 Then Debug.Print vaHours(497, 1)`. Take a look at the value in the Immediate Window. There should be something wrong with it which makes it different from all others in the column, perhaps Text instead of numeric. Of course, you might also find the value in the worksheet. Move it to another position in the sheet in case the error is related to the number 497. Remember that you can examine variable values by hovering the cursor or printing them to the Immediate Window while code execution is suspended after the crash.

Comment: Thanks Variatus. Sorry, I was in vacation and could not reply. I checked the values of vaHours by hovering the cursor and surprisingly I found the value of vaHours = 2, while .Work = 120. I was not able to understand the issue, so I deleted line 497 for the time and I will look into it later. Now though I am not getting the run-time error, the project file is only populated with vaTaskname, but other fields were not getting populated. I am playing around my code and trying to resolve. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line of code before that line: `If InCounter = 497 Then Debug.Print vaHours(497, 1)`. Take a look at the value in the Immediate Window. There should be something wrong with it which makes it different from all others in the column, perhaps Text instead of numeric. Of course, you might also find the value in the worksheet. Move it to another position in the sheet in case the error is related to the number 497. Remember that you can examine variable values by hovering the cursor or printing them to the Immediate Window while code execution is suspended.

Add a break point at the line `With .Tasks(vaTaskname(lnCounter, 1))`. You can do that by clicking on the grey bar to the left of the code, next to the indicated line. Then run the code. It will stop at the break point. Press F8 to advance one line. Pressing F5 will run the rest of the code, but since that means repeating the loop it will stop at the same break point again. While stopped you can ask any value in the Immediate Window or read variable values by hovering over them. Find out what's happening.

And please don't say you are sorry you were on leave. It makes me sad. :-)